# Postgres UPDATE statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.4

I have moved from mysql to psql, but find it hard to get my head around the UPDATE statement using multiple left joins.

How would you rewrite this in Postgres? (I am using postresql 9.4)

```
update task t 
    left join project p on t.project_id = p.id 
    left join client c on t.client_id = c.id 
    left join user u on t.user_id = u.id
set t.project_name = p.name, 
     t.client_name = c.name,
     t.user_name = u.name;
```

Any pointer will be welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+update+join  and of course the [examples in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html#AEN85309)

Comment: All the example only refer to one join. I need to do multiple joins.

Comment: There is no difference in the syntax between a join with one table and a join with multiple tables

Comment: You use only left joins, is it intentional - to update those rows in task table to null that have no `project`? With inner join to `project` it's something like this `UPDATE task
    SET project_name = p.NAME
     ,client_name = c.NAME
     ,user_name = u.NAME
    FROM project p ON task.project_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN client c ON task.client_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN user u ON task.user_id = u.id;`. To use a `LEFT JOIN` with `project` do a self-join to task or use subqueries in the `SET` part...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
WITH task_data AS (
    SELECT t.id,
        p.name AS project_name,
        c.name AS client_name,
        u.name AS user_name
    FROM task t 
        LEFT JOIN project p ON t.project_id = p.id 
        LEFT JOIN client c ON t.client_id = c.id 
        LEFT JOIN "user" u ON t.user_id = u.id
)
UPDATE task t
FROM task_data d
SET
    project_name = d.project_name, 
    client_name = d.client_name,
    user_name = d.user_name
WHERE t.id = d.id
```

I would be curious to see if there is a more efficient way